# Returning a list of output using URLLIB

Tags: python

I have been using the below to checking if a website is valid or not -

```
  from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
  from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
  req = Request("http://www.google.com/")
     try:
      response = urlopen(req)
    except HTTPError as e:
      print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
      print('Error code: ', e.code)
    except URLError as e:
      print('We failed to reach a server.')
      print('Reason: ', e.reason)
    else:
      print ('Website is working fine')
```

However, I need to input multiple websites at once (list created for the same) and get output like below-

```
www.google.com - Website is working fine
www.Facebook.com - Website is working fine
www.themoneytizer.net - We failed to reach a server.Reason:  [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
```

Kindly help with the code

Comment: www.themoneytizer.net this website doesn't work for me, I think that is the reason

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below. Hopefully you will get some idea.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
list_of_website = ['http://www.google.com/','https://paste.ubuntu.com/','http://algotoolz.com/']

for website in list_of_website:
  req = Request(website)
  try:
      response = urlopen(req)
  except HTTPError as e:
      print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
      print('Error code: ', e.code)
  except URLError as e:
      print('We failed to reach a server.')
      print('Reason: ', e.reason)
  else:
      print ('Website is working fine')
```

Comment: Please also check the website called www.themoneytizer.net .. may be this is not valid or have any issues with this .

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list to pass through all the website names
than use a for loop to iterate as below

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
websites = ["http://www.google.com/","http://www.facebook.com/"]
for web in websites:
   req = Request(web)
   try:
       response = urlopen(req)
   except HTTPError as e:
       print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
       print('Error code: ', e.code)
   except URLError as e:
       print('We failed to reach a server.')
       print('Reason: ', e.reason)
  else:
       print ('Website is working fine')
```